# Print 3 or 4 elements of an array containing 8 elements

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get 3 or 4 items out of an array containing 8 numbers (1-8). When I try to print an array of 3 or 4 items from the array I notice some strange behaviour. Most times it works but sometimes I only get some numbers and a 0 which isn't in the array. Like this [2, 5, 3, 0].

```
private int[] randomPeople() {
    int[] result = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    return getRandomPeople(result, arr);
}

private int[] getRandomPeople(int[] result, int[] arr) {
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
        number = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) { 
            if (number == result[j]) { //check if the random number is already in the list --> new random int
                j = 0;
                number = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length + 1);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { // adds the number to the new array and delete it in the old
            if (number == arr[j]) {
                result[i] = number;
                arr = searchDelete(arr, number);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    return result;
}
```

This method is for deleting the searched ID. You have to hand over an array and the integer which should be deleted.

```
private int[] searchDelete(int[] arr, int SRID) {
    int pos;
    for (pos = 0; pos < arr.length - 1; pos++) {
        if (arr[pos] == SRID)
            break;
    }
    while (pos < arr.length - 1) {
        arr[pos] = arr[pos + 1];
        pos++;
    }
    int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr2, 0, arr.length - 1);

    return arr2;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: @JoeC I tried to use the debugger several times, but the mistake appears for only like 5% of the times i got impatient and missed that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple and you can do it without helper methods:

```
public static int[] getRandomPeople(int[] arr, int total) {
    int[] res = new int[Math.min(arr.length, total)];
    Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<>();
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        int j = random.nextInt(arr.length);

        while (used.contains(j)) {
            j = (j + 1) % arr.length;
        }

        res[i] = arr[j];
        used.add(j);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the reason of this error is (probably) not the lack of debugging, but the lack of knowledge how `for` loop works, i'm gonna answer, although I suggest using @oleg.cherednik approach.

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

> for (initialization; termination;
>        increment) {
>       statement(s) }
>
> The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the
>   loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or
>   decrement a value.

So, in your `for` loop that checks if the random number is already in the list, you are doing `j=0`. Since this `for` loop iterates on `j` it is incremented at the end of each iteration, so it becomes `1` and check for index `0` is skipped. If the random number is in fact already there, but on index `0`, you are gonna miss it, and the final `result` array is gonna contain `0`, since it was initialized with zeroes.

Comment: How can i correct it?
set j = -1?
or is there another possible way?

Comment: Yes, that's the best way I guess. Besides changing the whole thing, like other answer suggests.

Comment: okay thanks for the information, but the problem continues.. thanks anyway